# Java algorithm to Xsl

Tags: java, xml, xslt, context-free-grammar, cyk

I'm working on an implementation of the CYK parsing algorithm for context free grammars.

However the hard part is I'm required to do this in XSL(A functional language) as opposed to a more procedural one that I'm quite familiar with - like Java.

I have a working implementation of an algorithm in Java but I would like to convert this to Xsl

```
   public boolean processString(String w) 
   // a string of any length like "aabaaba" or "my cat eats fish"
   {
        int length = w.length();
        table = new ArrayList[length][];
  for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
  {
        table[i] = new ArrayList[length];
        for (int j = 0; j < length; ++j)
          table[i][j] = new ArrayList < String > ();
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
  {
     Set<String> keys = terminals.keySet();
     for (String key : keys)
     {
        if (terminals.get(key).charValue() == w.charAt(i))
           table[i][i].add(key);
     }
  }
  for (int l = 2; l <= length; ++l)
  {
     for (int i = 0; i <= length - l; ++i)
     {
        int j = i + l - 1;
        for (int k = i; k <= j - 1; ++k)
        {
           Set<String> keys = variables.keySet();
           for (String key : keys)
           {
              String[] values = variables.get(key);
              if (table[i][k].contains((values[0]))
                    && table[k + 1][j].contains(values[1]))
                 table[i][j].add(key);
           }
        }
     }
  }
  if (table[0][length - 1].contains(startVariable))
     return true;
  return false;
  }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider to post a minimal but complete sample of the input you have and the output you want, together with a minimal but complete sample of code that can be run. That method takes a String and returns a boolean but uses variables like `terminals` or `startVariable` you have nowhere declared nor initialized, so it is not possible to read the code and understand what the code is supposed to do.

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33340967/cocke-younger-kasami-cyk-algorithm-in-the-xslt-and-transform-the-xml-to-produc